# Bootcamp or Boot Camp?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

As the title says, what is the correct version of these two words in English (GB)? I get mixed results when trying to look this up on Google.

I'm building a replacement website for a client that offers bootcamp/boot camp training classes. Her former website uses the word 'bootcamp' but after doing market research on her competitors for the purposes of search engine optimisation, I'm finding some companies are using 'boot camp' and some 'bootcamp'.

It's quite important to get this right, as search engines today ignore the keywords meta tag, meaning I can't add both versions, so I'm forced to use one of the other and I would like to get it right.

Comment: The [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bootcamp%2Cboot+camp&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbootcamp%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboot%20camp%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbootcamp%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboot%20camp%3B%2Cc0) massively favours "boot camp" for both British and American use. That won't tell you what's in vogue though.

Comment: You're asking for the one right variant, and the answer is that there isn't one. Neither is incorrect; both are in reasonably common use (as you point out). At least one online dictionary offers the solid compound. But most don't consider it to be sufficiently commonly used to mention. That's the English question answered (which is as far as we go on ELU), but it leaves you with your problem about what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct, especially on the web.

I did two corpus searches to see which came up more.

[Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

- Bootcamp: 39.
- Boot camp: 1101.

[News on the Web (NOW)](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/):

- Bootcamp: 4585.
- Boot camp: 8372.

So in American media and publications, *boot camp* is far more common. However, in web publishing, *bootcamp* and *boot camp* are both common, though *boot camp* still occurs more frequently. Especially on the web, *bootcamp* is frequent enough that it is a valid option as well.